# AngularJS $broadcast with multiple parameters

Tags: angularjs, events, broadcast

Can I have a `$broadcast $on` with multiple parameters,
something like:

```
$scope.$broadcast('event',$scope.item, $scope.item);
```

Is it possible to have something like this or something similar in any case ?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Just put the parameters into an object:

```
$scope.$broadcast('event', { a: item1, b: item2 })
```

Then access them from the second argument to the callback:

```
$scope.$on('event', function(event, opt) {
 // access opt.a, opt.b
});
```

Or if using ES2015 syntax you can unpack the arguments:

```
$scope.$on('event', (event, {a,b}) => {
 // access them just as a, b
});
```

Comment: Hi! please how can get the arguments in the $on?

Comment: @Llg Second parameter to the callback, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Documentation says:

> 'Optional one or more arguments which will be passed onto the event
>   listeners'

```html
$rootScope.$emit(event_name, p1, p2, p3);
```

Comment: This is not a `$broadcast` event.

Answer (score -1):

```
$scope.$broadcast('broadcast-my-event', anyVariable);
anyVariable = {key1: value1, key2: value2};
// or
anyVariable = [value1, value2, value3];
```

Comment: This doesn't explain how to use multiple parameters

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate in addition to help solve the problem.